# How can I create a swipeable calendar/date picker, that dynamically adds the previous & next months

Tags: calendar, svelte, swipe, swiper.js

I'm working on a calendar component for my web app, and really struggling to allow swiping through the months.

I created a `CalendarMonth` component that takes a `month` and `year` prop to render all the correct dates, so that part is done. Now I just need to be able to dynamically create these CalendarMonths so the user can swipe left and right on mobile to go through them.

Here's a REPL with a slimmed down version of what I have:
https://svelte.dev/repl/7626cce5508d4a73a6fe9d851e54d79a?version=4.2.0

I want to show one calendar at a time, and swipe left/right to go to the previous/next one.

I tried using Swiper.js to do this, and tried their "virtual slides" module but I couldn't seem to get that working either, so unsure if that was the right path or not. Perhaps Swiper isn't even needed? I'm all ears on how to tackle this!

Comment: Would it suffice if it is animated using a transition?

Comment: Yes but it'd still need to be swipeable, like other calendar apps on mobile